# Having issue in installing the cocopods on mac

Tags: ios, cocoapods, nativescript, homebrew

When I try to install cocoapods on my mac using sudo cmd, i.e "sudo gem install cocoapods".

It shows Failed to build gem native extension.
How to install cocoapods on mac,

```js
xxx-MacMini1 ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20220318-18160-1id5gxj.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi,/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi... yes
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... yes
checking for ffi_raw_call()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_raw_closure()... yes
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\= clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\=
compiling AbstractMemory.c
compiling ArrayType.c
compiling Buffer.c
compiling Call.c
compiling ClosurePool.c
compiling DynamicLibrary.c
compiling Function.c
Function.c:867:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_prep_closure_loc' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    ffiStatus = ffi_prep_closure_loc(closure->pcl, &fnInfo->ffi_cif, callback_invoke, closure, code);
                ^
Function.c:867:17: note: did you mean 'ffi_prep_closure'?
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi/ffi.h:269:1: note: 'ffi_prep_closure' declared here
ffi_prep_closure(
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Function.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: what version of Ruby do you have? (type `ruby -v`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a Ruby issue. Try installing version 2.6.3 using:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 2.6.3
```

and then try to run `sudo gem install cocoapods`. If this didn't work, try the following:

Open terminal and run

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then

```
rvm install ruby-2.6
```

This would install the ruby for you if its not yet installed. After this just update ruby to the new version using

```
rvm use ruby-2.6.3
```

Make ruby 2.6.3 your default

```
rvm --default use 2.6.3
```

Then hopefully you can run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```